# Get exactly next sibiling in XPATH 1.0 query

Tags: xml, xpath, plsql, sonarqube, xpath-1.0

I want to get with XPATH 1.0 the exactly next sibling element. Here is an example of the XML-Code:

```
<COMPILATION_UNIT tokenValue="GROUP" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="2">
  <GROUP tokenValue="GROUP" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="2"/>
  <BY tokenValue="BY" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8"/>
  <INTEGER tokenValue="3" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="0"/>
  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="COL_A" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="11"/>
  <INTEGER tokenValue="1" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="0"/>
  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="TEST" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="0"/>
  <EOF tokenValue="EOF" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="4"/>
</COMPILATION_UNIT>
```

In this scenario I want the next sibling element after the "BY"-Element. If I get it with "following-sibling" I have to specify the type of Element (e.g. IDENTIFIER) but it's always changing and it's too static. So is it possible to get the exactly following next Element without regard to the type?

Thanks for help

Comment: I solved it...:
For interested people:
BY/following-sibling::*[1]

Comment: You should put that as an answer and select it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...: For interested people: BY/following-sibling::*[1]